# Need help rendering a php script im symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to render a flat PHP script in symfony2/twig?

I tried their documentations but still get the same result. The PHP script is being rendered as text only for the example I'd like to render:

```
<?php 
echo "Hello world!"; 
?>
```

Comment: NOPE! You can't. And if that were possible would be a nonsense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOPE! You can't.
And if that were possible would be a nonsense.
However you can manually to enable the PHP Renderer as template engine:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

So on your controller class:

```
# src/AppBundle/Controller/HelloController.php
public function indexAction($name)
{
    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:Hello:index.html.php',
        array('name' => $name)
    );
}
```

And finally on your PHP template file:

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/Hello/index.html.php -->
<?php $view->extend('AppBundle::layout.html.php') ?>

Hello <?php echo $name ?>!
```

Well, as a side note you shouldn't to use/enable twig and php template together. The symfony docs stays it can produce " undesirable side effect in your application". So enable one or another, but not both.

Useful links:

- [How to Use PHP instead of Twig for Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html)